# Matching a String in a text file, and return back the meaning of the word in the client part (Scala)

Tags: scala, client-server

I would like to solve a problem where the client will send a word to the server, and server will run through the text file and return the meaning of the word that is typed by the user. My problem is when a matching word is typed, i will return the match word meaning, at the same time return back other "Word not found" (which is my control statement). So i would like to just return the meaning of the word only if the word is matched and found

Heres my code:

Server part

```
Future {
  //store local socket references for processing
  val client = socket
  try {
    // Get a communication stream associated with the socket
    val is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream))
    // Get a communication stream associated with the socket
    val os = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream)
    val inFile = new File(filename)
    val readFile = new Scanner(inFile)
    var input : String = null;
    while (true) {
      // Read from input stream
      var line: String = is.readLine() // read the word from client
      println("The client send " + line)
      while (readFile.hasNext()) {
        input = readFile.nextLine()
        println("From the file " + input)
          if (input.contains(line)) {
            os.println(input)
            os.flush()
          }
          else{
            os.println("Word not found")
          }
    }
    }
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace
  } finally {
    // Close the connection, but not the server socket
    client.close()
  }
}
```

Client Part

```
val is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.get.getInputStream))
val os = new PrintStream(client.get.getOutputStream) // write to server a strin

println("Please Input Ur word ")

val user = readLine
os.println(user)

while (true) {

  var line: String = is.readLine() //receive string from server
  println(line)
}
```

My text file is formatted this way:

super-very good or pleasant; excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach:

```
  var found = false;
  while (readFile.hasNext() && !found) {
    input = readFile.nextLine()
    println("From the file " + input)
      if (input.contains(line)) {
        os.println(input)
        os.flush()
        found = true;
      }
  }

  if(!found) {
      os.println("Word not found")
      os.flush()
  }
```

There are much more beautiful ways to do this, but as you seem to be a beginner, this is the simplest solution possible.

If you are interested in a functional approach, I will gladly help.

Hope this helps.